# Using Regex on encoded strings

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following regex:

```
@"{0}(.+?)(?:{1}(.{4}?))*(?:{2}(.+?))?{3}", "\\[\\[\\[", "\\|\\|\\|", "\\/\\/\\/", "\\]\\]\\]
```

To find items wrapped in [[[something]]], [[[something///comment]]].

I am using this to parse something on a web response ...

The problem is that in my web response I have a few things encoded as follows:

```
%5B%5B%5BPedido%20de%20Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D%5D%5D
```

So I am not able to identify that it starts with [[[ and finish with ]]] along with the other items.

Is there a way to solve this on the regex side?

Comment: You could expand the regex to look for escaped brackets as well as normal ones, but the regex would fast become unreadable. HtmlDecode on the string will handle this better. Any regex parsing of web responses is prone to break in edge cases or when someone maliciously sends values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unescape this string with helper functions like:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("%5B%5B%5BPedido%20de%20Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D%5D%5D");
```

will produce:

```
"[[[Pedido de Informação]]]"
```

`Note:` There is also `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` but required adding reference to `System.Web` which is not always wanted.

Comment: That is not an option because the string is an entire webpage and I do not want to unescape the entire content as I might have problems as after it I send the response to display the web page.

Comment: Still I would unescape it whole to the temporary variable used by regex.

Comment: I see but then I am translating the strings inside [[[ ]]] and replacing the [[[original string]]] by the "translated version". That is my problem ... I think I should replace them by a similar version (encoded or not)

Comment: @MDMoura: What about this: 1. Decode it, 2. escape everything, 3. re-encode it (Uri.EscapeDataString). That has the additional advantage that your translation gets encoded as well! (which is a good thing, if the web page expects an encoded string)

Answer (score 1):

If unescaping the string is not an option, you can use a [Noncapturing Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#grouping_constructs) `(?:...)` and an [Alternation Construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#alternation_constructs) `|` to allow `%5B` alternatively to `[` (same for `%5D` and `]`).

For example, `\\[\\[\\[` could be replaced by `(?:\\[\\[\\[|%5B%5B%5B)`. Adapting the complete regex is left as an exercise to the reader.

Note, however, that this will also match `[[[...%5D%5D%5D`, which might or might not be a problem in your case.